# Only count a download once it's served

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, ashx

We have this code which serves a download:

```
public class downloadRelease : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        -- snip --

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + OriginalFileName);
        context.Response.WriteFile(Settings.ReleaseFileLocation + ActualFileName);

        // Log download
        Constructor.VersionReleaseDownload.NewReleaseDownload(ActualFileName);
```

It works fine, except that the log download code runs as soon as the download starts seemingly, not when the download has fully completed as we expect.

Can someone explain why this is, and how to change it so it only logs when it's completed?  We don't want to count partial downloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [blog post](http://improve.dk/archive/2008/03/29/response-transmitfile-close-will-kill-your-application.aspx) has exactly same issue as yours and a solution too.

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.TransmitFile("Tree.jpg");
Response.Close();
// logging here
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks!  Works great.  It doesn't send the file size though so the download has unknown time left but I think I can fix that.

Comment: `context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString());` thanks for your code works a charm!

Comment: @TomGullen I didn't get the bounty for it.

Comment: don't worry I'm trying but it says I have to wait it's too soon

Answer (score 4):

The write response is an asynchronous process. It is managed by the container for the application. In your case the .NET/ASP.net run time is handling it. If you want to find out when the last chunk was sent you'll have to have some kind of callback/event on that [coming from the container/runtime]. In Java its the application server that gets this information [Glassfish, Tomcat etc]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this before writing the file:

```
context.Response.BufferOutput = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky... depending on how precise you want the logging to be it might even be that it is not possible... but there are the following options with the `Response` object :

- `BinaryWrite` / `Flush` / `Close`
- `TransmitFile` / `Flush` / `Close`

The first option requires you to read the file chunk after chunk calling `BinaryWrite` and `Flush` for every chunk...

The second option is easier to implement since it is just a call to `TransmitFile` and then to `Flush`.

After everything is sent and before logging you need to call `Close`.

In any case it can help to call `DisableKernelCache` before starting to send a response...

**BEWARE** that all of the above will show a noticeable *performance hit*!
This effect can be reduced by creating an in-memory-cache for the files you want to serve though...

As to the logging I would consider moving the logging code to the `EndRequest` event handler...

AFAIK this is the nearest you can get to your goal except writing your own TcpListener-based HTTP server or hacking IIS / HTTP.SYS .

Some reference links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.disablekernelcache.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried handling the EndRequest event of HttpApplication?

Or perhaps, using the ReleaseHandler() method of IHttpHandlerFactory, assuming that you mark your IHttpHandler as non-reusable?